# CodeIgniter: Current routes gives 404 and a blank page

Tags: codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter install with 2 sets of routers: one for static pages and one for a module.

The routes for static are working:

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
 $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

But the routes for this module display both a 404 when I go the its index and a blank page if I go to any of its child page.

```
$route['module/(:any)']               = 'module/index/$1';
$route['module/(:any)/(:any)']        = 'module/index/$1/$2';
$route['module/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'module/index/$1/$2/$3';
```

The module files are in views/module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error for the index part of the module was fixed with the following:

```
  $route['module'] = 'module/index';
```

The blank pages was due to a HMVC path error, but I was able to find the appropriate error by adding `ini_set ('display_errors', '1');` into index.php to find where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Oula !! It's normal.

It is because you created a route that matches everything :

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

With this one you catch all !! So it never reaches the others rules.

As Code Igniter : "Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones." you should put this one at the end of the list.

That said i think it is not a good idea to created a route that catches all....

Comment: could you please explain as to why you believe it to be a bad idea to have a 'catches all' route? (just curious)